# JavaScript Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am getting an "unexpected end of input" error on the last line below and if I keep removing the last line one at a time, the error prevails at the last line. I am trying this only with chrome.

I am using notepad++ and that doesn't throw up any errors or suggestions. I tried jedit but I am not too sure  if any syntax checking is active or not in either case. N++ gives me autocomplete suggestions though.

Any idea what is wrong with this. The AJAX did complete twice while testing but this suddenly stopped working. Can't figure out what broke this.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

function postevac()
{
    var location = document.getElementById("location").value ;
    var nameno = document.getElementById("Nameno").value ;
    var resources = document.getElementById("resources").value ;
    var persons = document.getElementById("persons").value ;
    var x  = new XMLHttpRequest();

    x.open("post", "http://localhost:5984/ch", true) ;

    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json") ;

    var y = {
            "location" : location ,
            "nameno" : nameno ,
            "resources" : resources ,
            "persons" : persons ,

        } ; 

    x.send(JSON.stringify(y)) ;


</script>
```

Comment: You might try using tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) to help you find and fix such issues.

Answer (score 5):

add `}` before the last `</script>` you need to close the function

Comment: Awww , this is so embarassing. I took a potty break and was wondering on my seat that javascript is something that simply likes to not work and somehow the entire world has gottten it wrong.